# Problemas com selector e jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando executar um código mas ele não funciona, não sei se é por erro de lógica na sua execução, veja, esse código é executado quando o botão `OK` é pressionado:

```
$('HTMLNEW').appendTo($(this).closest('.BOX').find('.DIVNEW')).css({
    animation: "---"
});
```

o HTML:

```
<div class="BOX">
    <div class="DIVNEW">

    </div>    
    <button id="ok">OK</button>
</div>
```

porém ele não executa o que é pedido, aliás, não executa nada.

Comment: O que é esse  `$('HTMLNEW')`?

Comment: @Sergio os códigos são meras representações, `HTMLNEW` são códigos `HTML` qualquer, como `<div id="...`

Comment: Você quer inserir um novo elemento/conteúdo dentro da `divnew` e depois manipular o css desse novo elemento/conteúdo? É isso? Está muito confusa sua pergunta.

Comment: Você tem certeza que esse seletor `HTMLNEW` existe? por um a caso isso não seria uma `variável`, `#id` ou `.classe`? Pessoalmente nunca vi nenhuma referencia a esse `HTMLNEW` em documentações

Comment: O teu código funciona... https://jsfiddle.net/vo5bco1r/ não percebo o teu problema... podes adaptar o jsFiddle e explicar melhor?

Comment: A pergunta realmente não tem nexo, o por que dela não funcionar para mim está relacionado ao `this` já que este era executado dentro de um setInterval.

Answer (score 2):

Use a função [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) para inserir o html no elemento desejado e use a função [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) para selecionar o elemento anterior ao seu botão.

> Note que o `append` sempre irá adicionar conteúdo no final do
>   elemento, não substituindo o que já existe, caso queira substituir o
>   que já exste use a função `html`, caso queira adicionar no início, use
>   o `prepend`.

```js
$('#ok').on('click', function () {
  var html = '<h1>Texto adicionado com append</h1>';
  
  $(this).prev('.divNew')
    .append(html)
    .css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="divNew">
  </div>
  <button id="ok">OK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: O código do AP funciona (https://jsfiddle.net/vo5bco1r/). Encontras-te algum problema nele que precise de correção?